# Lisp machine keyboard with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Vue's documentation mentioned legacy keyboards like the ones one MIT/Lisp machine, Symbolics keyboards, Knight keyboard and space-cadet keyboard. Just wondering if these machines are actually in used and have the browsers that support running Vue?